# Downloading a zipped file requiring login from a website (morphosource) HTML using rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I know there are similar questions like this on stackoverflow, but after looking through them, I still have not found a way to download the file I need. I have a list of http web addresses. When I put an address into my browser when I am logged in to the website of interest (MorphoSource), it automatically downloads a zipped folder. I need to do this from R so that I can download many of these folders in a loop.

here is one such http address (though nothing will happen without being logged in): `"http://www.morphosource.org/index.php/Detail/MediaDetail/DownloadMedia/media_id/119/media_file_id/52"`

I have gotten furthest using the code below but I still get an error message that I am `Submitting with 'NULL'` and when I look at the file that is downloaded, it is about 8kb when it should be over 50,000kb

```
  library(rvest) 
    login<-"https://www.morphosource.org/LoginReg/form"
    pgsession<-html_session(login)
    pgform<-html_form(pgsession)[[2]]  
    filled_form<-set_values(pgform, username="TestingPackage@gmail.com", password="testingpackage")
    submit_form(pgsession, filled_form)
download.file("http://www.morphosource.org/index.php/Detail/MediaDetail/DownloadMedia/media_id/119/media_file_id/52", "testfile")
```

I am fairly new to R and totally new to the idea of downloading zipped folders through web addresses in R so I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just need to do some session management for you:

```
morphosource_dl <- function(media_id, # if end of URL is /media_id/119/media_file_id/52 then this is 119
                            media_file_id, # if end of URL is /media_id/119/media_file_id/52 then this is 52
                            overwrite = TRUE, # overwrite file if it already exists?
                            .progress = TRUE, # show a download progress bar?
                            username = Sys.getenv("MORPHOSOURCE_EMAIL"), # pass in here or store in ~/.Renviron
                            password = Sys.getenv("MORPHOSOURCE_PASSWORD")) { # pass in here or store in ~/.Renviron

  suppressPackageStartupMessages({
    library(httr, warn.conflicts = FALSE, quietly = TRUE, verbose = FALSE)
    library(rvest, warn.conflicts = FALSE, quietly = TRUE, verbose = FALSE)
  }) 

  # Start a sessiion
  res <- httr::GET(url = "https://www.morphosource.org/Splash/Index")

  # login
  httr::POST(
    url = "https://www.morphosource.org/LoginReg/login",
    httr::add_headers(
      Referer = "https://www.morphosource.org/LoginReg/form"
    ),
    body = list(
      username = username, 
      password = password
    ),
    encode = "form"
  ) -> res

  # if successful
  if (length(html_nodes(httr:::content(res), xpath=".//*[contains(., 'You have been logged in')]")) > 0) {

    httr::stop_for_status(res) # make sure it really was successful

    # do this to get filename
    httr::HEAD(
      url = sprintf(
        "https://www.morphosource.org/index.php/Detail/MediaDetail/DownloadMedia/media_id/%s/media_file_id/%s",
        media_id, media_file_id
      )
    ) -> res

    fil <- gsub("^.*filename=", "", res$headers["content-disposition"])

    httr::GET(
      url = "https://www.morphosource.org/index.php/Detail/MediaDetail/DownloadMedia/media_id/119/media_file_id/52",
      httr::write_disk(fil, overwrite = overwrite),
      if (.progress) httr::progress()
    ) -> res

    if (.progress) cat("\n")

    return(fil)

  } else {
    message("Error logging in")
    httr::stop_for_status(res)
  }

}
```

Your URL was `http://www.morphosource.org/index.php/Detail/MediaDetail/DownloadMedia/media_id/119/media_file_id/52` (it was *actually* `https://www.morphosource.org/index.php/Detail/MediaDetail/DownloadMedia/media_id/119/media_file_id/52` and that is an important difference).

That means the "media id" is `119` and the "media file id" is `52`.

If you do the right thing and make entries in your `~/.Renviron` for:

```
MORPHOSOURCE_EMAIL=me@example.com
MORPHOSOURCE_PASSWORD=aBetterP@s$w0rDThanThis
```

and refresh your R session, then you can do:

```
morphosource_dl("119", "52")
## Downloading: ... MB
## [1] "Morphosource_AMNH-M-100635_M119-52.zip"
```

and it will be downloaded for you.

Otherwise you can do:

```
morphosource_dl(
  media_id = "119", 
  media_file_id = "52", 
  username = "donotdothis@example.com",
  password = "embeddingCredentialsInScriptsIsNotTooBright"
)
```

and it will download it still.

In both instances it returns the name of the file.

You can control whether it will overwrite files (`TRUE` by default) with the `overwrite` parameter and whether you want a progress bar or not (`TRUE` by default) with `.progress`.

The issue you were having is that `download.file()` knows nothing of the underpinnings of `rvest` which is `curl` and `httr` (and `xml2`). So `download.file()` can't pickup the session cookie that your `rvest` call generated. You likely could have just made a call to `httr::GET()` and the `https` version of the download link and use `httr::write_disk()` in it after what you started with, but the function above encapsulates it all into one action and also figures out the filename (which you'd have had to set manually) before.

We just did it the "long way" and mimicked what the browser did with `GET` and `POST`:

[image]

Comment:  if this did answer ticking the answer icon next to the answer helps others know it worked